# Parse text file and convert to csv

Tags: python, pandas

I need to convert a big text file to a csv file, while parsing the text and getting only the information I need to create a new table. This is what I have:

```
# -- name1 --
country: Italy
age:30
height: 1,8
weight: 80
# -- name2 --
age:20
height: 1,6
weight: 50
# -- name3 --
City: Berlin
country: Italy
age:33
height: 1,7
weight: 82
```

And the output I need is:

```
Name    Age    Height
name1   30      1,8
name2   20      1,6
name3   33      1,7
```

I suppose that it is doable to do using Pandas but I am having some difficulties to start coding this. Can you please help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: what have you written until now?

Comment: Oh it may be possible with pandas, but it will certainly be easier without it!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it without using pandas as well.

```
with open('res.txt') as file:
  contents = file.read().split('\n')
  name,age,height = [],[],[]
  for ele in contents:
    if ele.__contains__('#'):
        lis = [name if name!='#' and name!='--' else '' for name in ele.split()]
        name.append(' '.join(lis))
    elif ele.__contains__('age'):
        age.append(ele.split(':')[1])
    elif ele.__contains__('height'):
        height.append(ele.split(':')[1])
with open('output_csv.csv','a') as file:
  file.write('Name,Age,Height\n')
  for ele in list(zip(name,age,height)):
    file.write(f'"{ele[0]}",{ele[1]},"{ele[2]}"\n')
```

Comment: And what if a name value contained a comma like `John, second of name`? Why don't you use the csv module to write a csv file?

Answer (score 2):

Not that hard, but it needs a custom parser.

Rules:

- a new *name* starts with a line beginning with a pound sign (`#`)

  - the format is `# -- name --` : the name is the second field when splitting on `--`
- *fields* lines contain:

  - a field name
  - a colon (`:`)
  - optional blank characters
  - a field value
  - optional blank characters including the end of line
- in the end you want a csv for the fields name, age and height, with capitalized headers

Code could be:

```
with open('file.txt') as fdin, open('file.csv', newline='') as fdout:
    wr = csv.DictWriter(fdout, fieldnames=['Name', 'Age', 'Height'],
                        extrasaction='ignore')  # ignore unwanted fields
    row = {}
    wr.writeheader()                            # write the header line
    for line in fdin:
        if line.startswith('#'):                # process a name line
            name = line.split('--')[1].strip()
            if len(row) != 0:                   # if we have a row write it
                wr.writerow(row)
            row = {'Name': name}                # initialize a new row
        else:
            field, value = line.split(':')      # process a field line
            row[field.strip().capitalize()] = value.strip()
    if len(row) != 0:                           # do not forget the last row
        wr.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer requires all keys to be added manually and ignores the key-value pairs for country and city.

If you would like to use pandas, you might as well do the following:

```py
import re
import pandas as pd

# Create empty list to store dicts for every block
dict_list = []
# Split string into blocks using the comment at the beginning
blocks = re.split('#.*--', string)
# Iterate over all blocks
for block in blocks:
    # Use regex to find all key-value pairs, assuming they are split by
    # either ':' or ': '.
    tuples = re.findall('(.*):\s?(.*)', block)
    # Create an empty dictionary to convert the list of tuples
    # returned by findall
    d = {}
    # Iterate over all tuples in list
    for t in tuples:
        # Create a key-value pair from the tuple
        d[t[0].lower()] = t[1]
    if tuples:
        # Append the dictionary to dict_list
        dict_list.append(d)

# Create a data frame from the list of dicts.
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_list)
```

The general challenge is that your data is in form of a key-value pair rather than tabular format which `pd.read_csv()` could process. Assuming that it's not in fact a `.yaml` file (then just use `pyyaml` and create a data frame from dict), you need to parse the file.

Please see the inline comments for further explanation.